# Octopus Deploy Powershell Silently Continue doesn't seem to work

Tags: powershell-2.0, octopus-deploy

I have this pre-deploy powershell script running:

```
sc.exe stop "someservice" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I'm expecting that the `someservice` will be stopped if it exist, and if it doesn't, the error will get swallowed.

However, when I push a new service out, I get an error saying the service isn't found.

Inb4 - The service needs to be installed in a special way (a third party service), so i can't use octopus deploy's service installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the desired result is because sc.exe is not a powershell cmdlet, it is a windows server program. Instead, use the `stop-service` cmdlet

`Stop-Service -Name ServiceName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

[get-help stop-service -online](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849790.aspx)